# Privileges necessary to drop and re-create Foreign Key Constraint in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, foreign-keys

What privileges should my username(schema1) have in order to be able to drop a foreign key constraint on Table_1(schema2) referencing Table 2(schema2) ?

How should I check if I have those privileges ?

If I do not, what GRANT statement must I issue from a SYSDBA role in order for my username to be able to drop and re-create a constraint on a table.

Comment: if both tables are in the same schema, then there's no need any privilege, otherwise `references` privilege should be granted.

Comment: The tables are in a different schema and I am in a different schema. Where should I check if I have REFERENCES privilege ?

Comment: look up `user_tab_privs` data dictionary view.

Comment: No entry in the USER_TAB_PRIVS. But I don't have it for another username where I am able to do it ? Any other ROLE given to the username can overrride the lack of REFERENCES privilege ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connected as `scott`, I'll create a table and foreign key constraint that references another table in the same schema.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL>
SQL> create table test_d as select * From dept;

Table created.

SQL> alter table test_d add constraint pk_td primary key (deptno);

Table altered.

SQL> create table test (deptno number constraint fk_d references test_d (deptno));

Table created.
```

---

Connect as another user (`mike`) and try to drop the foreign key constraint owned by `scott`:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> -- without any grants - of course it doesn't work
SQL> alter table scott.test drop constraint fk_d;
alter table scott.test drop constraint fk_d
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> -- Barbaros suggested to GRANT REFERENCES ON test TO mike, but that won't work either.
SQL> -- REFERENCES is used to let someone else ... well, "reference" your table:
SQL> alter table scott.test drop constraint fk_d;
alter table scott.test drop constraint fk_d
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

OK, we saw what doesn't work. Let's now see what *works*:

```
SQL> -- SCOTT granted ALTER: grant alter on test to mike;
SQL> -- Let's check it:
SQL> select table_name, privilege from user_tab_privs where grantor = 'SCOTT';

TABLE_NAME                     PRIVILEGE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
TEST                           ALTER

SQL> -- OK, now - drop the constraint
SQL> alter table scott.test drop constraint fk_d;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

---

Finally, to answer the question: table owner has to grant `alter` on that table. `SYS`(`DBA`) doesn't have to be involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

To add or drop constraints on another user's tables, you would need "ALTER ANY TABLE".

Comment: I want to know the privileges necessary to do it.

Comment: @learner Did you try it? Sys DBA account can grant the ALTER ANY TABLE to you.  If you are the schema owner, you don't need the priv to alter your own table.

Comment: Is ALTER ANY TABLE a privilege on the USER or ROLE ?

Comment: @learner the priv can be granted through a role or directly granted to the user

Comment: I'd disagree; ALTER ANY TABLE means "Alter any table in any schema and compile any view in any schema." That is **too powerful** privilege for someone who is supposed to alter one table, for one user. Generally speaking, users should be granted only the minimum set of privileges which allow them to work without problems. Don't grant something they don't need; if it turns out that they do need additional privilege, grant it. That's related to popular GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE - roles popular in "old" Oracle database versions. Nowadays, it is suggested to grant minimal set or privileges.

Comment: @Littlefoot It is wise to limit priv's.  In our environment, the OP's [original poster's] action would generally be taken using the schema owner account, although we do allow it with special elevated priv's [controlled through a privileged access management system] like ALTER ANY TABLE .  Personally, I prefer not to mess around with other app's DDL, because, in my view, the app owner should have full change control responsibilities.

Comment: No problem, Roger. We agree that we disagree :) which is perfectly OK.